# How to move Ubuntu into RAM AFTER booting, whilst deleting as much as possible?

Tags: boot, server, ram

This post suggests how to move Ubuntu into RAM

http://dreamlayers.blogspot.com/2012/10/running-linux-from-ram.html

I'm wanting to do pretty much the same, but on a low memory system 512MB or less.

So, given a "standard" Ubuntu 16.04 server, what directories could I delete to trim it down to the minimum before moving the whole thing into RAM and running from there? Put another way, what is not essential?

By "minimum" I mean basically the ability to run many of the command command line utils plus run scripts, interpreters i.e. Python.

The ultimate idea is to be able to reformat the hard disk that the server booted from, and then after that still have most of the "common" command line tools available for carrying out the various tasks required to install a new operating system onto the top of the existing hard disk.

My specific question being, what can I delete from a base install of Ubuntu server 16.04 whilst still having a functional OS for common uses?

Comment: By definition, you can delete anything you won't ever use. Your question is a bit ill-defined in that respect. Define what are your uses and you'll have the list of what you cannot remove.

Comment: @spectras To still have most of the "common" command line tools available for carrying out the various tasks required to install a new operating system onto the top of the existing hard disk.  I'm trying to identify easy targets for deletion - i.e. man pages can obviously go. what else can obviously go if I just want to run command line utils? I have seen some source files - probably not needed? What else can be dropped without impacting most common command line usage?

Comment: Make a list of the commands you want, find out which packages they are in. Keep those packages and their dependencies. Remove the rest. We are not seers, we cannot guess which command line utils you use. Same goes with python interpreter: we cannot guess which modules your scripts use. Same with system services: do you need ssh? ftp? a fileserver? a vpn server? a webserver? which ones? with what features enabled? **Write down your requirements!**.

Comment: Or said simply: we cannot guess what _you_ call “common uses”, and it most probably is different from _my_ common uses. And if you don't want to do this effort, and just want “reasonable common uses”, then basically the base install is “reasonable defaults covering most common uses”.